# How to extract specific data from a text file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

This is a text file `accountinfo.txt`:

```
Luke TonyHawk123! luke33@gmail.com  
Cindy JasonVoorhees123! cindy5@yahoo.com
```

I want to ask the user for their email to print the values (i.e. their username and password) on the left.  For example, if the user inputs `luke33@gmail.com`, it should return `Luke` and `TonyHawk123`.
I've tried using `strip` and `split`, but my logic is wrong.

Work I've done so far:

```
account_file = open("accountinfo.txt")
email_string = account_file.read().strip().split()
while True:
    email_account = input("Enter the email linked to your account: \n")
    if email_account == "":
        continue
    if email_account in email_string:
        # ???
    else:
        print("This email doesn't exist in our records.")
        main()
```

Comment: Checking `email_account in email_string` doesn't work, because `("Luke", "TonyHawk123!", "luke33@gmail.com")` is what's in `email_string`. You would need to extract the email address and probably put it into a dictionary for retrieval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) here:

```
import csv

with open("accountinfo.txt") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=" ")
    email = input("Enter the email linked to your account: \n")
    for row in reader:
        if row and row[2] == email:
            print(" ".join(row[:2]))
            break
    else:
        print("This email doesn't exist in our records.")
        main()
```

You can also split each line manually:

```
with open("accountinfo.txt") as f:
    email = input("Enter the email linked to your account: \n")
    for line in f:
        if email and email in line:
            print(line.rsplit(" ", 1)[0])
            break
    else:
        print("This email doesn't exist in our records.")
        main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how the information of each e-mail is arranged but if they´re in the same file. I did a similar program, but the information of each username was separated with a sting like this: "----------------".     So I iterated through lines until it found the e-mail. Once it found it, I would print every line until it found another "----------------". So all the user´s information was between those lines. You can do something similar depending on how your information is arranged. You can iterate through the lines of the file with:

```
validation = False
for line in file:
   if email in line:
      validation = True
      while line != "---------------":
         print(line, end="")

if validation == False:
  print("This email doesn't exist in our records.")
```

Comment: There's [`for .. else`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement in python which designed specially for this purpose.